# Are there efforts to retrieve any future tech from the Atlantic?

Tags: apocalypse-troll

A LOT of future technology splashed into the Atlantic during Colonel Leonovna's and CTF's fight with the Trolls and Kanga tender.

Some (like the tender) are probably vaporized by nukes. But some is likely to still be salvageable - Terran fighter was destroyed but not vaporized (never mind the safety capsule she survived in), many Troll fighters were destroyed by human weapons and not future tactical nukes.

Given how valuable the surviving Troll fighter in the USA would become, are there efforts to retrieve any future tech from the Atlantic?

Comment: It's not mentioned in the book, but they would be stupid not to try, even though the wreckage is presumably at the bottom of the mid-Atlantic which is not the easiest place to mount salvage operations. Weber mentioned in 2019 he was planning to write a sequel. Maybe we'll see it there.

Comment: A sequel would be nice maybe John Ringo could get on the tram and write another council war book too lol

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez While they would be stupid not to try, they also have a complete, working Troll fighter in their hands, as well as someone who can explain the technology.  So not recovering the bits and pieces wouldn't be a deal breaker. Also remember that in the original timeline humans went from zero to better tech than the Kangas just by examining Kanga missile tech.  OTOH interesting about a sequel.  I've always thought that a sequel that explored the lead up to meeting the Kangas in the new timeline would be interesting.

Comment: @PeterM The only Troll technology is in the hands of the USA. I know that the ending of the book points towards the formation (eventually) of a One World government, but until then I'm sure that China, the USSR and other nations would love to get their own hands on a piece of the wreckage.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez  From the last paragraph in the OPs question isn't clear as to whom the sunken tech would be valuable.  It's not valuable per se to the USA, but perhaps would be valuable to say the Chinese (who were kept in the dark all along).  The latter point would be more obvious if the OP had addressed the disparity of tech distribution with more than just a passing reference. (But it is moot anyway as you pointed out it isn't mentioned in the book)